# How to store data into temp table from while loop SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I want to query data from example table by Row_indexes = 1 (or 2 or 3), and then store the data into 3 temp tables within a while loop.

The data looks like this:

```
SK_mem | row_indexes | memberID
-------+-------------+----------------
   1         1         AAAAA
   1         2         BBBBB
   1         3         CCCCC
   2         1         DDDDD
   2         2         EEEEE
   3         1         FFFFF
   3         2         GGGGG
   3         3         HHHHH
```

I want to create 3 temp table #a,#b,#c

#a is like this

```
SK_mem|  row_indexs|  memberID
1          1         AAAAA
2          1         DDDDD
3          1         FFFFF
```

#b is like this

```
SK_mem|  row_indexs|  memberID
1          2         BBBBB
2          2         EEEEE
3          2         GGGGG
```

#c is like this

```
SK_mem|  row_indexs|  memberID
1          3         CCCCC
3          3         HHHHH
```

I write a whole loop to do it, but only #c table within a while loop are saved. How can I save #a,#b tables within loop. Please advise. Thank you so much.

```
DECLARE @Counter INT , @MaxId INT

SELECT @Counter = min(Row_indexs) , @MaxId = max(Row_indexs) 

FROM #USFHP_Identify
select @data_table='#test'+ convert(nvarchar(255),@Counter)

 
WHILE(@Counter IS NOT NULL
      AND @Counter <= @MaxId)

BEGIN

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#@data_table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #@data_table

   SELECT *
   into #@data_table
   FROM #Exampletable WHERE Row_indexs = @Counter
 
    
   SET @Counter = @Counter  + 1  
      
END
```

Comment: 99 times out of 100, if you're using a while loop inside an SQL procedure you're doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * INTO #@data_table` is not going to do what you are thinking.  It's going to create a temp table that is actually named `#@data_table`.  So, every time you iterate through the loop `#@data_table` is recreated and overwritten, and it will contain the contents whatever the last iteration through the loop produces.

This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you using these temp tables for?  You might just be able to use `#Exampletable` directly when you need, in a CTE or a JOIN.

Comment: i want to join #a,#b,#c tables on sk_mem to get all membeID into a row, I want to change long table into wide tabl., but I need to break down the table into 3 temp table first. And i want to it automatically to process in loop. Is that feasible?